# Remote desktop and wmi

Tags: windows, wmi, remote-desktop, remote-server

For some reason, after performing a system restore, when I try to execute a certain script while logged on using remote desktop, or by connecting to the computer via WMI, the script starts but then it crashes for an unknown reasons.

When I run the script while logged in to the computer as local user - it works just fine.

I checked the permissions of the script, of the the WMI service, nothing...

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask this question on Super User site, cause i think it can depends from permisions

Comment: You need to post the script here. WMI security is different than RPC, so we'll need to see the code before we can assess which forum is best suited for this question.